# Bad operator Error occurs on > operator

Tags: java

```
 if ((list.get(i)) > (list.get(maxInd))) {
     maxInd = i;
 }
```

error giving in on operator, where list is an object of LinkedList and MaxInd contains the first element of linked list while i is the variable of for loop

---

```
  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(3);

    int maxInd = 0;
    int list_size = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        if((list.get(i)) > (list.get(MaxInd))) {
            maxInd = i;
        } // end if condition    
    } // end for loop
```

Comment: Can you show all the code, in particular how you declare the linked list?

Comment: What type of object are you storing on the list? If It is a custom class, you have to overload the operator

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk you can't overload these operators in Java

Comment: I have upload my code please see it..

Comment: @Zar Thanks for the info. I didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your LinkedList uses a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), meaning that the elements of the list are treated as `Object` types. The simplest solution is to use a type parameter:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
// ...
```

Or you can use a cast, but only only if you're sure that all the elements in the list are Integers:

```
if ((Integer)(list.get(i)) > (Integer)(list.get(MaxInd))) {
    MaxInd = i;
}
```